# Phoenix / Elixir: How to add args to terminate event?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using channels to implement a chat. When one person leaves the chat, I'd like to inform specific clients that that person has left.

This is what I have found:

```
  def terminate(reason, socket) do
    Logger.info "terminated!!!!"
    Logger.info inspect(reason)
    Logger.info inspect(socket)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

Is there a way to customize `terminate/2` so that I can pass an ID to it or something? Like in `handle_in/3`, there's a `payload` argument to the method so I can pass it stuff.

Comment: You could store the user ID in the `socket.assigns`, and retrieve it from there maybe, if it's the user ID that you need? :)